# Upload VHD to Azure using the Azure SDK

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

Is there a way to upload a VHD to Azure using the Azure SDK? I am aware of the same process for uploading it via Powershell (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/createupload-vhd) , but I would like to achieve that using the SDK, so that it can be performed using a Linux environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, we can install Azure [CLI 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cli-install-nodejs) or [CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) on your Linux environment.

About how to use **CLI 2.0** to upload VHD from Linux environment, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/upload-vhd).

```
az group create --name myResourceGroup --location westus
az storage account create --resource-group myResourceGroup --location westus --name mystorageaccount --kind Storage --sku Standard_LRS
az storage account keys list --resource-group myResourceGroup --account-name mystorageaccount
az storage container create --account-name mystorageaccount --account-key key1 --name mydisks
az storage blob upload --account-name mystorageaccount --account-key key1 --container-name mydisks --type page --file /path/to/disk/mydisk.vhd --name myDisk.vhd
```

About how to use **CLI 1.0** to upload VHD from your Linux environment, please refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/upload-vhd-nodejs?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json).

```
azure config mode arm
azure group create myResourceGroup --location "WestUS"
azure storage account create mystorageaccount --resource-group myResourceGroup --location "WestUS" --kind Storage --sku-name PLRS
azure storage account keys list mystorageaccount --resource-group myResourceGroup
azure storage container create --account-name mystorageaccount --account-key key1 --container myimages
azure storage blob upload --blobtype page --account-name mystorageaccount --account-key key1 --container myimages /path/to/disk/mydisk.vhd
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I think you want to upload a VHD to Azure on local Linux like do it on Windows via powershell. So as the offical [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/classic/create-upload-vhd) said for Linux via Azure CLI, it's you wanna. However, it's an old way to create and upload a VHD to Azure using Azure Service Management (ASM) Mode. Now, Azure Resource Management (ARM) had instead of ASM APIs. If you want to create a VHD using ARM API, you can refer to the REST API [`Create a virtual machine image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/manageddisks/images/images-create) or Python SDK for [`Managed Disks`](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample_azure-mgmt-manageddisks.html).

If you just need to upload a VHD from local to Azure Storage, you only refer to the offical tutorial [`How to use Azure Blob storage from Python`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage) to do it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It seems that there is not a Python-SDK equivalent to the "vm image create" CLI command, right? I was looking in the SDK approach in the first place, but it seems that this call does not exist in the SDK.

Comment: @GeorgeTs Indeed, I could not find any ways in Python SDK which be equivalent to the "vm image create", even in the old SDK.